# Enter-PSSession to remote server fails with “access is denied”

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to use winrm remote vm, I can connect to the localhost, but I can't connect to the other remote machine, the error is "access is denied".

Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide `-Credential` parameter:

```
Enter-PSSession –ComputerName Server –Credential Domain\UserName
```

Comment: Assuming `Enable-PSRemoting` has been run on both machines, and Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value *` has been run on yours (I have seen this generate an Access Denied error)

Comment: I tried,but it still not working.the error doesn't change.

Comment: You might need to set `-Authentication Default`

Answer (score 6):

So I was having the EXACT same issue as this user and found the issue.  Basically I was running the commands as my Domain Admin account but the servers are locked down to not accept network connections from Domain Admin accounts in Group Policy as a security measure.  Once changing the command credentials to run as my non domain admin account and an account allowed network access with administrative permissions the enter-pssession command worked perfectly.  What I don't understand is why the test-wsman command appears to work.